# Health monitoring application (store medical data) for personal use

Tags: gratis, linux, offline

Is there an offline, gratis Linux application (preferably in the Debian / Ubuntu repositories) that can store, visualize and export medical data like weight, blood pressure, heart rate, taken medication?

The data should help me to gather long-time medical data like weight, blood pressure, heart rate, taken medication, ... so that I can give that to my physician in case I get ill. (see [TED talk](http://www.ted.com/talks/talithia_williams_own_your_body_s_data) for the motivation)

The export should be in a usable format (XML / CSV / JSON / YAML).

The software is for personal use (hence: only one user).

The software can be used through the browser, but it should be offline (I don't want to give my data away).

It should be aimed for amateur users. (GNU Health is too complex and seems to be aimed for complete hospitals)

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest simply using [Libra Office Calc](http://www.libreoffice.org/discover/calc/) - it fits all your requirements other than being used through the browser.  Simply have one column for each of your required data items.  I would add the use of a DVCS such as mercurial to allow you to track changes and as a backup mechanism.

- Gratis *Yes*
- Linux *Available for Linux, Mac & Windows*
- store *Yes in a spreadsheet format*
- visualize *Graphing available*
- export medical data like weight, blood pressure, heart rate, taken medication *Yes you can have whatever columns you need*
- The data should help me to gather long-time medical data like weight, blood pressure, heart rate, taken medication *These would be your columns - I would suggest one page per month and one new spreadsheet per year*
- The export should be in a usable format (XML / CSV / JSON / YAML) *Multiple formats are available for export*
- The software is for personal use *Personal or Business use allowed but I would not recommend trying to use for more than a couple of people*
- The software can be used through the browser, ***No!***
- but it should be offline ***Yes*** unless you put it online
- It should be aimed for amateur users. *I would **NOT** recommend using a spreadsheet for professional use*
- GNU Health is too complex and seems to be aimed for complete hospitals *GNU Health is aimed for hospitals from the website "[GNU Health](http://health.gnu.org/index.html) is a free Health and **Hospital** Information System" there is also the excellent [GNUMed](http://wiki.gnumed.de/bin/view/Gnumed) but that is also aimed at health professionals.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider [Libreoffice Base](http://www.libreoffice.org/discover/base/) with a local database.

- Gratis *Yes*
- Linux Available for Linux, Mac & Windows
- store *Yes it's a database*
- visualize *Integrates with Calc and Chart*
- export medical data like weight, blood pressure, heart rate, taken medication *Yes you can have whatever data you need*
- The data should help me to gather long-time medical data like weight, blood pressure, heart rate, taken medication *These would be your data fields*
- The export should be in a usable format (XML / CSV / JSON / YAML) *Multiple formats are available for export and you can interface to other database types*
- The software is for personal use *Personal or Business use allowed*
- The software can be used through the browser, *There is at least one project to make this possible if you really must*
- but it should be offline *Yes unless you put it online*
- It should be aimed for amateur users. *Amateur or professional but for professional I would suggest [GNU Health](http://health.gnu.org/index.html) or [GNUMed](http://wiki.gnumed.de/bin/view/Gnumed).*
- GNU Health is too complex and seems to be aimed for complete hospitals *GNU Health is aimed for hospitals from the website "[GNU Health](http://health.gnu.org/index.html) is a free Health and Hospital Information System" there is also the excellent [GNUMed](http://wiki.gnumed.de/bin/view/Gnumed) but that is also aimed at health professionals.*